# PHP GET MySQL order by if not empty echo else echo how

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have a page where I display all products in stock, I want them to be ordered by ID or name or Date etc.

A way to do it is by getting the order by a link on table row title and get it like this

```
$order_by = $_GET['order'];
if (!empty($order_by)) {
    echo "id";
} else {
    echo "$order_by";
}
```

Now we must in some way echo this to the query but I do not know how, the query is like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($database,"SELECT * FROM `stock` order by `id` ASC");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

I tried inserting the entire PHP $order_by replacing the order by 'id' but it gives me errors.

Any idea how to echieve this?

Comment: Is this valid php? Semi-colons outside the braces?

Comment: Your ORDER BY clause needs replaced with the PHP: "SELECT * FROM stock ORDER BY `$order_by` ASC". (Note that $order_by must be a valid column name or you will get an error.

Comment: Error is one of the most important information when you debug your code.  If you don't add it to your question, it's not possible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check if `$_GET['order']` is valid, to do that use `in_array()` and check if order received is in an array of allowed values ( whitelist array ). I don't think that `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is enough to protect order by clause becouse it is a column name, not a value. If validation fails use the default column name ( `id` ).

```
$order_whitelist = [ 'id', 'name', 'date' ];

if ( !empty( $_GET['order'] ) && in_array( $_GET['order'], $order_whitelist, true ) )
    $order_by = $_GET['order'];
else
    $order_by = 'id';
```

Now it is safe to build a query, for that purpose `sprintf()` function can be useful.

```
$result = mysqli_query( $database, sprintf( "SELECT * FROM `stock` order by `%s` ASC", $order_by ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire "order by " does not need to be replaced.  Just insert what you want order by.

```
<?php
$order_by = $_GET['order'];
if(!empty($order_by)){
    $result=mysqli_query($database,"SELECT * FROM `stock` order by `".$order_by."` ASC");
    $rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {do something}
?>
```

Note that this is not sanitized and can lead to SQL injection.

Comment: (make it not empty) or (don't have the clause to begin with)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :-

```
$order_by = $_GET['order'];

    if(empty($order_by)){
            $order_by='id';
    }

    if(!empty($order_by)){
        $result=mysqli_query($database,"SELECT * FROM `stock` order by `".$order_by."` ASC");

        $rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
```